# Can I make an application to start in another workspace automatically?

Tags: applications, workspace

When I start an application, I want to move it automatically into another workspace. For example, when I type 'virtualbox' on terminal or on synapse-indicator, I want virtualbox to open in another workspace. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use `devilspie`. It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elementary OS does not currently have this feature. There is an [open feature request in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1065153)